# Understanding implementation of Local binary pattern

Tags: python, scikit-image, lbph-algorithm

I am trying to understand the scikit-image implementation of Local Binary Pattern **in detail.** I understand how LBP works, but I fail to get some points in the implementation.

**My main question is: Is the weight matrix in scikit-imgae the same as for example in this image here?**

[image of weight matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOLdf.jpg)

When trying to find the answer on my own I faced some problems:

- [texture.py](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/main/skimage/feature/texture.py) uses a function (_local_binary_pattern() ) that I couldnt find at the beginning - but I guess it is defined in [_texture.pyx](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/main/skimage/feature/_texture.pyx). Am I right?
- How does the function *bilinear_interpolation[cnp.float64_t, double, double](
  &image[0, 0], rows, cols, r + rp[i], c + cp[i],
  b'C', 0, &texture[i])* work? What do the box brackets mean? The "&" point to the adress of the variables, right? Where is the result of the function call stored? I dont see anything like x = bilinear_interpolation(...)
- Where can I find the definitions of functions like bilinear_interpolation?

Thanks for any advice and help!

Best,
Bernhard

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer by just trying the algorithm on images.
The weight matrix in the local binary pattern in scikit-image is as follows.

It starts at 3 o clock and the goes counterclockwise. For 8 points this would result in:

> --------4--------
>
> --8-----------2--
>
> 16--------------1
>
> --32----------128
>
> --------64-------

I got the other questions regarding the code open - so I am still happy about any comments etc..